# Casting Object to static nested class in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, static, nested

Consider this code:

```
public class OuterClass<T,P> {
  private InnerClass<T,P>[] array; //field

  public OuterClass() { //constructor
     this.array = (InnerClass<T,P> [])new Object[30]; //problematic line

 static class InnerClass<T,P> { //definition of my static nested class 
        ...}
```

Now a main method like this:

```
OuterClass<String,Integer> oc = new OuterClass<>();
```

For the following code I get a ClassCastException. The problem lies somewhere in the OuterClass constructor. This kind of casting from Object to my static nested class throws an exception, and I do not understand why. How would I go about creating an array of static nested class objects(that pass the same generic types as OuterClass)?

Comment: Have you tried `this.array = new InnerClass[30]` ?

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm working with generics. Java doesn't allow creation of generic arrays. There's a workaround of casting an array of Object, but in my case I'm getting a ClassCastException.

Comment: Have you considered possibility to switch to `List<InnerClass<T, P>>` instead of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create generic array with `Array.newInstance`

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public OuterClass() { //constructor
    this.array = (InnerClass<T,P>[]) Array.newInstance(InnerClass.class, 30);
}
```

Example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class OuterClass<T,P> {
    public InnerClass<T, P>[] array; //field

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public OuterClass() { //constructor
        this.array = (InnerClass<T,P>[]) Array.newInstance(InnerClass.class, 30);
    }

    static class InnerClass<T, P> { //definition of my static nested class
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass<Integer, Integer> outerClass = new OuterClass<>();
        InnerClass<Integer, Integer> innerClass = new InnerClass<>();
        outerClass.array[1] = innerClass;
        System.out.println(outerClass.array[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried `this.array = new InnerClass[30]` ?

> This doesn't work because I'm working with generics. Java doesn't allow creation of generic arrays.

Indeed creating a generic array like this:

```
this.array = new InnerClass<T, P>[30];
```

would be illegal, Eclipse gives the error: `Cannot create a generic array of OuterClass.InnerClass<T,P>`

Or if `InnerClass` were a generic type variable, you can't use it to create an array:

```
public <InnerClass> OuterClass() {
    this.array = new InnerClass[30];
}
```

You get: `Cannot create a generic array of InnerClass`

However, creating a raw array of the concrete type `InnerClass` (that then gets converted to a `InnerClass<T, P>[]`) is totally fine:

```
public OuterClass() {
    this.array = new InnerClass[30];
}
```

You do get an `unchecked` warning, but it can be ignored, since you don't keep a raw reference to the array around there is no (immediate) chance of heap pollution.